# GCP Cloud Run with command line arguments

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am new to Docker and GCP and I need to deploy a very basic Python app (calculator) on a Cloud Run service. I have 3 files calc.py, Dockerfile and requirements.txt. The application is taking 3 arguments from the user directly from the command line when the application start: `number1`, `number2` and `operationType`

I have been able to build my Docker image and I am running that image with docker `run -it calculator`

I just deployed that same image on GCP Container Registery before to create a new Cloud Run service. After selecting my image from the GCP Container Registery, the Cloud Run settings is asking me to fill up 2 things and I don't know what to write:

```
1) Container command (Leave blank to use the entry point command defined in the container image.
Container arguments)
2) Arguments passed to the entry point command.
```

Comment: You need to implement your application as an HTTP Request Response system (similar to a web server). Parameters can be passed as HTTP query parameters. Study one of the many Cloud Run examples on how to build apps for Cloud Run. https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts

Comment: Those fields are optional. Can you attach a screenshot please. You should not be asked those.